# SQL Select value from other table based on column value as treshold

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a **SQLite** query which returns a user name and how much a user spent (done by SELECT SUM() from the different table).

| Name | Spent |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | 700 |
| Mike | 400 |
| Steve | 100 |

I have another table which contains discount amount with corresponding treshold:

| Treshold | Discount |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 5 |
| 400 | 10 |
| 600 | 15 |

I need to find what discount each user has (if it does at all). So results would look like this:

| Name | Spent | Discount | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | 700 | 15 | 595 |
| Mike | 400 | 10 | 360 |
| Steve | 100 | 0 | 100 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `LEFT` join of your query to the 2nd table and aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.Spent,
       COALESCE(MAX(t2.Discount), 0) Discount,
       t1.Spent * (1 - 0.01 * COALESCE(MAX(t2.Discount), 0)) Total 
FROM (SELECT name, SUM(Spent) Spent FROM table1 GROUP BY name) t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Treshold <= t1.Spent
GROUP BY t1.name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0fbff9c1c8ab3e28723488c719b7e475).

Answer (score 0):

I am in a hurry. Sorry.

```
with a as (
select name, sum(spent) spe
from test1
group by name)
select a.name
       , a.spe
       , max(tres)
       , max(disc)
       , spe -spe * (0 || '.' || disc) total
from test2, a 
where tres <= a.spe
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=80cb62090a482f71427a71ca82a089fa)